# django ajax display nothing in for loop

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i have to use for loop inside my ajax request , i used django inlineformset , when admin selects an item it has to return back the price , but it doesnt work in for loop

```
class Item(models.Model):
     items = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3)#i have to return this price
     def __str__(self):
        return self.items 

class Invoice(models.Model):
     admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     items = models.ManyToManyField(Item,through='ItemsInvoice')

class ItemsInvoice(models.Model):
     invoice_no = models.ForeignKey(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3)#when selecting an item , the price return back and write in the price field
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def check_price(request):
   item = request.GET.get('invoice-0-item',None)
   price = Item.objects.get(id=item).price
   print(price)
   data = {
      'price':price,
   }
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

and i dont know how to iterate through the number of forms to achieve this

```
@login_required
def check_price(request):
   for i in range(length of forms):
       item = request.GET.get('invoice-'+i+'-item',None)
       #etc
```

```html
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{items.management_form}}
                <div class="p-1 pr-2 pb-1 text-xs border border-black rounded-lg flex flex-wrap" style="direction: rtl;">
                   
                    <div class="flex w-8/12 lg:w-9/12">
                        
                        <div class="">
                              customer name  :
                          </div>        

                        <div class="w-10/12 ml-8 border-b border-gray-600 border-dotted">
                            {{form.customer | add_class:'bg-transparent w-full text-center focus:outline-none customer' }}
                            {% if form.customer.errors %}
                            <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{form.customer.errors}}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- table -->
                <div class="mt-1 border border-black" style="direction: rtl;">
                    <!-- header -->
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap grayBG text-sm text-white">
                        <div class="w-3/12  border-r text-center">
                            item
                        </div> 
                        <div class="w-1/12  border-r text-center">
                            quantity
                        </div>  
                        <div class="w-1/12  border-r text-center">
                            price
                        </div>            
                    </div>
                    <!-- inputs -->
                    <div id="allInp" class="text-right">
                        {% for item in items.forms %}

                        {{item.id}}
                        <div class="flex flex-wrap grayBG text-sm text-black inp">
                            <div class="w-20 md:w-3/12 p-2 border-r text-center">
                                {{item.item | add_class:'w-full item rounded-lg text-center focus:outline-none py-1' }}                    
                                {% if item.item.errors %}
                                <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.item.errors}}</div>
                                {% endif %}
            
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-16 md:w-1/12 p-2 border-r text-center ">
                                {{item.quantity | add_class:'rounded-lg dana text-center focus:outline-none py-1 w-full'}}                    
                                {% if item.quantity.errors %}
                                <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.quantity.errors}}</div>
                                {% endif %}

                            </div> 
                            <div class="w-16 md:w-1/12 p-2 border-r text-center ">
                                {{item.price | add_class:'rounded-lg price text-center focus:outline-none py-1 w-full' }}                    
                                {% if item.price.errors %}
                                <div class="redCOLOR pb-1 my-0 text-center rounded-lg w-full md:w-6/12 mx-auto">{{item.price.errors}}</div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>                                   
                        
                        </div>                
                        {% endfor %}

                    </div>          
                </div>        
            </div>

            <div class="w-6/12 text-center mt-1 mx-auto mb-6">
                <button type="submit" class="w-full bg-white text-gray-900">submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    <script>    
       function sellingPrice () {
        let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".dynamic-form > .inp");
        for(let i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
        $('#id_invoice-0-item').change(function(){
            var item = $(this).val();
            // console.log(item)
            $.ajax({
                url:'/ajax/price_validate/',
                data:{
                    'invoice-0-item':item
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    if (data.price){
                        inp[i].getElementsByClassName("price")[0].value = data.price
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('price doesnt provided')
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    }
    </script>
```

i have to give the retuned price to the price field , but it doesnt work in for loop
is there a way to achieve it please ?!

**updated**
forms.py

```
class InvoiceItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Item.objects.all(),empty_label='---',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'sellingPrice()'}))
class Meta:
    model = ItemsInvoice
    fields = [
        'item','quantity','price'
    ]

class CustomerInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = [
            'customer'
        ]

CustomerInvoiceInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Invoice,ItemsInvoice,form=InvoiceItemForm,
         fields=('item','quantity','price'),extra=1
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion, your question is now clear. You must use jQuery [**`change`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event for your select tag.

Change your script to:

```
$('.inp select.item').change(function() {
    let elm = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url:'/ajax/price_validate/',
        data:{
            // elm.attr("name"): elm.val()
            // OR keep it simple
            "item_id": elm.val()
        },
        success:function(data){
            if (data.price){
                elm.closest("div.inp").find("input.price").val(data.price);
            }
            else{
                alert('price doesn't provided')
            }
        }
    })
})
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def check_price(request):
    query = request.GET
    data = {
        'price': Item.objects.get(id=query.get("item_id")).price,
    }
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: it returns http://127.0.0.1:9002/ajax/price_validate/?invoice-0-item=12 500 (Internal Server Error)  , doesnt work

Comment: @HunarMohammed, please share your traceback. What error?

Comment: it shows in the console , i returned json version

Comment: and also i should change the ( data:{
                    'invoice-0-item':item },'  to `'invoice-[i]-item':item ` the 0 should be dynamic

Comment: which form should i use ? and also it expects to change id items in the template `'invoice-[i]-item':item` im not good at js and ajax

Comment: i have used `InvoiceItemForm` it only returns number of fields (0,1,2) nothing else

Comment: @HunarMohammed, I don't understand you question now.

Comment: just return back price value in Item when selecting an item in ItemsInvoice give the value in to price field in ItemsInvoice

Comment: @HunarMohammed, i edited my answer with different approach.

Comment: but we have to change the ajax code as well `'invoice-0-item':item` to make `invoice-0-item` dynamic , change number per loop , thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230867/discussion-between-nksm-and-hunar-mohammed).